# No network devices available Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 16.04

I am a new user to the Linux world.
I installed Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot Windows 10.

Unfortunately, I can not access Wifi networks in Ubuntu although I can access them in Windows 10.

I have scraped through all the related links in the web, but none of them resolved my issue.

PFA, some useful screenshots of important information about my laptop

[image: laptop specifications]

[image: additional drivers]

I would really appreciate if you could explain the solution step by step.

**Update 1**

Following Łukasz D. Tulikowski comments, I observed

My Wireless driver is Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168, it needs Kernel 4.6 to function.

I upgraded my kernel to 4.6 and now I do not see "No network devices available". However, I now see "Wifi-networks device not ready".

Thus closing this bug and opening another bug "Wifi-networks device not ready"

**Update 2**

Need to blacklist acer_wmi to Enable Wifi.

```
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Finally, wifi is working fine.

Comment: I do not see 'Enable Wifi', in fact I only see the links mentioned in the screenshot(pls check top right side of the screenshots)

Comment: No Issues, In fact I am stuck with this problem since 4 days, and still have not cracked it :(

Comment: does this solve your problem? `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`

Comment: Unfortunately no it does not

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with this network device (Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168). With my new Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, kernel version 4.8 and the correct firmware it should work out of the box (I read in other posts) - but it didn't.

The solution that is shown as "Update 2" in the question is working for me (but I have no idea why - where did you get this?):

`"echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"`

Comment: @Zanna: Looks like an answer to me since the question says that this module black-listing solved the issue. It's not a duplicated answer either.